# Как отображать формы на картинке в PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qlayout

**Имеется:**

Недоделанная программа-игра, похожая на *Duck Hunt*. Имеются 3 линии форм: для начала и остановки игры, выбора режима скорости и результатов. В самом низу расположена картинка-поле для будущих уток.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Проблема:**

Реализацию уток я оставляю на кнопку (накладываю картинку утки на кнопку) и потом эту кнопку буду двигать, не суть. В общем, при попытке рисования на данной картинке кнопки (для будущей утки) = она появляется справа (приложил картинку), а НЕ на самой картинке-поле внутри.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить эту ошибку, то-есть чтобы кнопку-утку можно было ставить на картинку (код и сама картинка-поле будут приложены снизу).

**Код:**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QLineEdit, QFormLayout, QGroupBox, QRadioButton, QMainWindow, QWidget, QGridLayout, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QPainter, QColor, QPixmap, QIcon

WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600
WINDOW_WIDTH = 600
WINDOW_NAME = 'Истребитель уток'
WINDOW_ICON_NAME = 'Images\\main_logo.png'

MAIN_FONT = 'Times'
FONT_HEADER_SIZE = 13
FONT_BODY_SIZE = 8


class FormBuilder(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.create_all_forms()
        self.fill_forms()
        self.create_layers()

    def create_all_forms(self):
        self.task_label = QLabel()

        self.control_label = QLabel()
        self.start_button = QPushButton()
        self.quit_button = QPushButton()

        self.mode_label = QLabel()
        self.first_rbutton = QRadioButton()
        self.second_rbutton = QRadioButton()
        self.third_rbutton = QRadioButton()

        self.results_label = QLabel()
        self.play_time_qedit = QLineEdit(placeholderText="Время игры")
        self.play_attempts_qedit = QLineEdit(placeholderText="Число попыток")

        self.background_image_label = QLabel()
        background_image = QPixmap("backimage.png")
        self.background_image_label.setPixmap(background_image)

    def fill_forms(self):
        self.task_label.setText("Задача: убейте всех уток за установленное время.")
        self.task_label.setFont(QFont(MAIN_FONT, FONT_HEADER_SIZE))
        self.task_label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.control_label.setText("Управление")
        self.start_button.setText("Начать игру")
        self.quit_button.setText("Закончить игру")

        self.mode_label.setText("Режим:")
        self.mode_label.setFont(QFont(MAIN_FONT, FONT_HEADER_SIZE))
        self.first_rbutton.setText("1-я скорость")
        self.first_rbutton.setChecked(True)
        self.second_rbutton.setText("2-я скорость")
        self.third_rbutton.setText("3-я скорость")

        self.results_label.setText("Результаты:")
        self.results_label.setFont(QFont(MAIN_FONT, FONT_HEADER_SIZE))
        self.play_time_qedit.setDisabled(True)
        self.play_attempts_qedit.setDisabled(True)

    def create_layers(self):
        outline = '''
                    QGroupBox {
                        margin-top: 2ex;
                    }
                    QGroupBox::title {
                        subcontrol-origin: margin;
                        left: 3ex;
                    }
                    '''

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        task_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        task_layout.addWidget(self.task_label)
        main_layout.addLayout(task_layout)

        self.control_groupbox = QGroupBox(self.control_label.text())
        self.control_groupbox.setStyleSheet(outline)
        control_groupbox_layout = QHBoxLayout(self.control_groupbox)
        control_groupbox_layout.addWidget(self.start_button)
        control_groupbox_layout.addWidget(self.quit_button)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.control_groupbox)

        self.mode_groupbox = QGroupBox(self.mode_label.text())
        self.mode_groupbox.setStyleSheet(outline)
        mode_groupbox_layout = QHBoxLayout(self.mode_groupbox)
        mode_groupbox_layout.addWidget(self.first_rbutton)
        mode_groupbox_layout.addWidget(self.second_rbutton)
        mode_groupbox_layout.addWidget(self.third_rbutton)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.mode_groupbox)

        self.result_groupbox = QGroupBox(self.results_label.text())
        self.result_groupbox.setStyleSheet(outline)
        result_groupbox_layout = QHBoxLayout(self.result_groupbox)
        result_groupbox_layout.addWidget(self.play_time_qedit)
        result_groupbox_layout.addWidget(self.play_attempts_qedit)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.result_groupbox)

        background_image_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        background_image_layout.addWidget(self.background_image_label)
        main_layout.addLayout(background_image_layout)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.build_skeleton_with_basic_settings()
        self.create_and_connect_grid()

    def build_skeleton_with_basic_settings(self):
        self.setFixedSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT)
        self.setWindowTitle(WINDOW_NAME)
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon(WINDOW_ICON_NAME))

    def create_and_connect_grid(self):
        self.main_grid = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        form_builder_object = FormBuilder()
        self.main_grid.addWidget(form_builder_object, 0, 0, Qt.AlignTop)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Картинка-поле:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Потому что вы родителю задали лейаут, а надо все на игровом поле позиционировать в абсолютных координатах того же родителя. А лучше в таких случаях использовать QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene и QGraphicsItem

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, в абсолютных координатах в моем коде не получится выполнить так, потому что у меня Grid стоит и к нему всё добавляется.

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что если стоит лейаут, то любой добавляемый виджет будет этим лейаутом соответствующим образом выравниваться, поэтому QGraphics...

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, хорошо, попытаюсь что-то сделать с QGraphics, спасибо

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, еще раз добрый день!) Можете, пожалуйста, подсказать, как можно проверять какая нарисованная фигура была нажата в QGraphics?

Comment: Там в QGraphicsItem есть целый набор методов mousePress mouseRelease и так далее, наследуйте и  переопределяйте

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel, QHBoxLayout, \
    QVBoxLayout, QLineEdit, QFormLayout, QGroupBox, QRadioButton, \
    QMainWindow, QWidget, QGridLayout, QApplication, QSizePolicy
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QSize
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QPainter, QColor, QPixmap, QIcon

WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600
WINDOW_WIDTH = 600
WINDOW_NAME = 'Истребитель уток'
WINDOW_ICON_NAME = 'Images\\main_logo.png'
#WINDOW_ICON_NAME = 'Ok.png'

MAIN_FONT = 'Times'
FONT_HEADER_SIZE = 13
FONT_BODY_SIZE = 8


class FormBuilder(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.create_all_forms()
        self.fill_forms()
        self.create_layers()

    def create_all_forms(self):
        self.task_label = QLabel()

        self.control_label = QLabel()
        self.start_button = QPushButton()
        self.quit_button = QPushButton()

        self.mode_label = QLabel()
        self.first_rbutton = QRadioButton()
        self.second_rbutton = QRadioButton()
        self.third_rbutton = QRadioButton()

        self.results_label = QLabel()
        self.play_time_qedit = QLineEdit(placeholderText="Время игры")
        self.play_attempts_qedit = QLineEdit(placeholderText="Число попыток")

        self.background_image_label = QLabel()
        background_image = QPixmap("backimage.png")
        self.background_image_label.setPixmap(background_image)

    def fill_forms(self):
        self.task_label.setText("Задача: убейте всех уток за установленное время.")
        self.task_label.setFont(QFont(MAIN_FONT, FONT_HEADER_SIZE))
        self.task_label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.control_label.setText("Управление")
        self.start_button.setText("Начать игру")
        self.quit_button.setText("Закончить игру")

        self.mode_label.setText("Режим:")
        self.mode_label.setFont(QFont(MAIN_FONT, FONT_HEADER_SIZE))
        self.first_rbutton.setText("1-я скорость")
        self.first_rbutton.setChecked(True)
        self.second_rbutton.setText("2-я скорость")
        self.third_rbutton.setText("3-я скорость")

        self.results_label.setText("Результаты:")
        self.results_label.setFont(QFont(MAIN_FONT, FONT_HEADER_SIZE))
        self.play_time_qedit.setDisabled(True)
        self.play_attempts_qedit.setDisabled(True)

    def create_layers(self):
        outline = '''
            QGroupBox {
                margin-top: 2ex;
            }
            QGroupBox::title {
                subcontrol-origin: margin;
                left: 3ex;
            }
        '''

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        task_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        task_layout.addWidget(self.task_label)
        main_layout.addLayout(task_layout)

        self.control_groupbox = QGroupBox(self.control_label.text())
        self.control_groupbox.setStyleSheet(outline)
        control_groupbox_layout = QHBoxLayout(self.control_groupbox)
        control_groupbox_layout.addWidget(self.start_button)
        control_groupbox_layout.addWidget(self.quit_button)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.control_groupbox)

        self.mode_groupbox = QGroupBox(self.mode_label.text())
        self.mode_groupbox.setStyleSheet(outline)
        mode_groupbox_layout = QHBoxLayout(self.mode_groupbox)
        mode_groupbox_layout.addWidget(self.first_rbutton)
        mode_groupbox_layout.addWidget(self.second_rbutton)
        mode_groupbox_layout.addWidget(self.third_rbutton)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.mode_groupbox)

        self.result_groupbox = QGroupBox(self.results_label.text())
        self.result_groupbox.setStyleSheet(outline)
        result_groupbox_layout = QHBoxLayout(self.result_groupbox)
        result_groupbox_layout.addWidget(self.play_time_qedit)
        result_groupbox_layout.addWidget(self.play_attempts_qedit)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.result_groupbox)

        background_image_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        background_image_layout.addWidget(self.background_image_label)
        main_layout.addLayout(background_image_layout)


class Label(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, path, w, h):
        super().__init__()
        self.setPixmap(QPixmap(path).scaled(w, h))


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.build_skeleton_with_basic_settings()
        self.create_and_connect_grid()
        
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv   
        self.my_widget = QWidget(self.form_builder_object.background_image_label)
        self.my_widget.setFixedWidth(self.size().width()-30)

        self.layout_left = QHBoxLayout()
        for i in range(2):
            label = Label("bullet.png", 10, 40) 
            self.layout_left.addWidget(label) 
        self.layout_left.addStretch(1)
        
        self.layout_center = QHBoxLayout() 
        self.layout_center.addStretch(1)
        self.button = QPushButton() 
        self.button.setFixedWidth(25)
        self.button.setIcon(QIcon("down.png"))
        self.button.setIconSize(QSize(20, 20))
        self.layout_center.addWidget(self.button)
        self.layout_center.addStretch(1)
        
        self.layout_right = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout_right.addStretch(1)
        for i in range(2):
            label = Label("heart_.png", 30, 30) 
            self.layout_right.addWidget(label) 
            
        my_layout = QHBoxLayout(self.my_widget)      
        my_layout.addLayout(self.layout_left, 0)
        my_layout.addLayout(self.layout_center, 1)
        my_layout.addLayout(self.layout_right, 0)
        
        
        label = Label("bullet.png", 10, 40) 
        self.layout_left.insertWidget(0, label)
        
        label = Label("heart_.png", 30, 30) 
        self.layout_right.addWidget(label) 
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    def build_skeleton_with_basic_settings(self):
        self.setFixedSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT)
        self.setWindowTitle(WINDOW_NAME)
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon(WINDOW_ICON_NAME))

    def create_and_connect_grid(self):
        self.main_grid = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.form_builder_object = FormBuilder()                               # + self.
        self.main_grid.addWidget(self.form_builder_object, 0, 0, Qt.AlignTop)  # + self. 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добрый день! Спасибо за Вашу помощь, код работает, как мне и нужно было по условию, но я понял, что передвижение форм (уток) будет затруднительным с данным кодом из-за создания множества Layout'ов. Сейчас пытаюсь реализовать эту программу с помощью QGraphic, но у меня возникли трудности, не могли бы Вы, пожалуйста, помочь с моим новым вопросом, который уже был выложен?

Comment: @GunTHE я не понимаю о каких трудностях вы говорите.

Comment: я задал новый вопрос про QGrapich и трудности возникли там)